# Strange levels on UART TX

Tags: voltage, uart, level

I am trying to get the boot chatter from a UART on IOT device. When powered up TX line goes high as expected (3.3V), but when it starts "talking" - scope shows that hi/lo levels swings are around 200 mV - between 3.26V - 3.18V.

Any helpful clues how to go about to get it sorted up, please?

Comment: Check related external resistors?

Comment: Did you already connect it somewhere, or it is unconnected when showing 100mV swing? What device it is and to which pin you are connecting to?

Comment: I can't seem to open the UART's datasheet link. What does it say about the logic levels. Does it need a pulldown?

Comment: Sure you're monitoring the actual TX line and not it weakly coupled into something else like the RX line?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two outputs driving one against each other? Like one trying to to signal and the other resting high? A cross wired connection all in all.

Comment: Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.